# Ruby - Unexpected tIDENtifier, expecting $end

Tags: ruby, syntax

I just started to learn Ruby. I'm creating a simple program in it, I'm still not sure on how to use it. This is my code:

```
=begin
Filename: GameCompanyPoem.rb
Program Name: Poem Generator
Version 1.0
Created: March 7th, 2013
Purpose: To generate a poem based on key words given by the user
=end
print 'The following program will ask you to input words. Based on the words you input it will generate a poem. Now, please enter a name. '
name = gets.chomp
print 'Please enter a mammal. '
mammal = gets.chomp
print 'Now please enter a colour. '
colour1 = gets.chomp
print 'We are almost done! Please enter a place or location now. '
place = gets.chomp
print 'Now enter a verb. '
verb1 = gets.chomp
print 'And another verb. '
verb2 = gets.chomp
print 'Your poem will now be generated. Press enter to continue.
space = gets.chomp
print 'Someone by the name of ' + name + 'had a little' + mammal + ', little ' + mammal + ', little ' + mammal + ',' + name + 'had a little ' + mammal + 'its fleece was' + colour + 'as snow. It followed her to ' + place + 'one day, ' + place + 'one day, ' + place + 'one day, it made the children ' + verb1 + 'and ' + verb2 + 'to see a ' + mammal + 'at' + place + '."'
```

When I run it, every space in the last method (print) has this error:

Unexpected tIDENtifier, expecting $end

at every space, if I fill it in then it's gone but it goes onto the next space

Comment: Closing quote is missing on `'Your poem will now be generated. Press enter to continue.` The syntax highlighter makes that more apparent.

Comment: and you have an extra '"' (double quote) at the end of the last string. See my answer for complete fix

Comment: and it should be coulor1, not colour, as @limelights mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Michael and Blaine :D

Answer (score 2):

A nifty trick in many languages including Ruby called interpolation

```
print "Someone by the name of #{name} had a little #{mammal}, little #{mammal}, little #{mammal}, had a little #{mammal} its fleece was #{colour} as snow. It followed her to #{place} one day, #{place} one day, #{place} one day, it made the children #{verb1} and #{verb2} to see a #{mammal} at #{place}."
```

Hmm it may not rhyme anymore.

There's a bit more to it. Look up Ruby Interpolation for details. But basically ruby runs into #{something} it replaces it with the result of something.

`print "1 + 2 = #{1 + 2}"` will print

1 + 2 = 3

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
print 'Your poem will now be generated. Press enter to continue.'
print 'Someone by the name of ' + name + 'had a little' + mammal + ', little ' + mammal + ', little ' + mammal + ',' + name + 'had a little ' + mammal + 'its fleece was' + colour1 + 'as snow. It followed her to ' + place + 'one day, ' + place + 'one day, ' + place + 'one day, it made the children ' + verb1 + 'and ' + verb2 + 'to see a ' + mammal + 'at' + place + '.'
```

Comment: Also, he's missing the variable `colour`, it should be `colour1` ! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I fixed the colour variable and found I was missing an apostrophe somewhere in there :)